# Given curve $y$ determine point $A$ on that curve such that tangent on curve $y$ through point $A$ makes largest angle with positive part of $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

> Given a curve $y$ = $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ determine point $A$ on that curve such that tangent on curve $y$ through point $A$ makes largest angle with positive part of $x$-axis (in terms of absolute value)

---

Let $y = f(x)$, let coordinates of $A$ be $A(x_0, f(x_0))$ and let $\theta$ be angle we want to maximize.

Slope of a tangent line through point $A$ is $f'(x_0) = \frac{-2x_0}{(1+x_0^2)^2}$, so it means that $\tan \theta = \frac{-2x_0}{(1+x_0^2)^2}$, $\theta = arctan(\frac{-2x_0}{(1+x_0^2)^2})$. Now I need to find derivative of $arctan(\frac{-2x_0}{(1+x_0^2)^2})$, equalize that with $0$ to find extreme point, and prove that it's a maximum point. We have $(arctan(\frac{-2x_0}{(1+x_0^2)^2}))'$ = $\frac{4x_0^5-4x_0}{(1+x_0^2)^4 + 4x_0^4}$, from where I get, when I equalize with $0$, $x_0 = \pm1$. Point $x_0 = -1$ is a maximum point, but that isn't on postive part of $x$-axis. Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: Instead of dealing directly with the maximum angle, reason that it will coincide with the point of maximum slope when $x>0$. Then it becomes an exercise in finding the positive value of $x$ where the derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ reaches its maximum value, and the corresponding $y$ value. These will give you the coordinates of $A$.

Comment: If I do it that way, derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$, which has it's maximum at point $x = -\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$, but I don't quite see how to find it's maximum when $x > 0$

Comment: That's where its maximum positive slope is. But the exercise says "in terms of absolute value" so you also need to see where its maximum negative slope is, i.e. its minimum slope.

Comment: And that will be at point $x = \frac{\sqrt3}{3}$! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.